# Average salary for each department

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I'm trying to get the average employee salary for each department. I am expecting two rows because one department doesn't have any employees assigned to it.

Can someone please tell me how to rectify this issue. Thanks in advance to all who answer and your expertise.

Below is my test CASE and inaccurate result.

```
CREATE TABLE departments(  department_id, department_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'IT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Sales' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'DBA' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date, salary,  department_id) AS
SELECT 1, 'Lisa', 'Saladino', DATE '2001-04-03', 100000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Abby', 'Abbott', DATE '2001-04-04', 50000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Beth', 'Cooper', DATE '2001-04-05', 60000, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Carol', 'Orr', DATE '2001-04-06', 70000,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Vicky', 'Palazzo', DATE '2001-04-07', 88000,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Cheryl', 'Ford', DATE '2001-04-08', 110000,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Leslee', 'Altman', DATE '2001-04-10', 66666, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Jill', 'Coralnick', DATE '2001-04-11', 190000, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'Faith', 'Aaron', DATE '2001-04-17', 122000,2 FROM DUAL;

SELECT d.department_id,
         d.department_name,
         round(avg(e.salary) over (partition by e.department_id)) avg_sal
  FROM   departments d
         JOIN employees e
         ON (d.department_id = e.department_id)


DEPARTMENT_ID    DEPARTMENT_NAME    AVG_SAL
1    IT    76111
1    IT    76111
1    IT    76111
1    IT    76111
1    IT    76111
1    IT    76111
2    DBA    133333
2    DBA    133333
2    DBA    133333
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `AVG` aggregation function rather than analytic function and aggregate by the primary key for the department:

```sql
SELECT d.department_id,
       MAX(d.department_name) AS department_name,
       ROUND(AVG(e.salary)) avg_sal
FROM   departments d
       INNER JOIN employees e
       ON (d.department_id = e.department_id)
GROUP BY
       d.department_id;
```

Or, you can just aggregate the `employees` table and use a correlated sub-query to get the name:

```sql
SELECT department_id,
       ( SELECT department_name
         FROM   departments d
         WHERE  d.department_id = e.department_id ) AS department_name,
       ROUND(AVG(salary)) avg_sal
FROM   employees e
GROUP BY
       department_id;
```

Or aggregate before joining the tables:

```sql
SELECT d.department_id,
       d.department_name,
       e.avg_sal
FROM   departments d
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT department_id,
                ROUND(AVG(salary)) avg_sal
         FROM   employees
         GROUP BY department_id
       ) e
       ON (d.department_id = e.department_id);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ggBqbPx1)

Comment: @MTO if I use your second solution how would I be able to add a count(*) to determine how many employees are in each department. Thanks in advance for your time, patience and expertise

Comment: @Pugzly Just add `, COUNT(*) AS num_employees` to the `SELECT` clause (which should work on either query) [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EDtX0zgY)

Answer (score 1):

You need **inner join** and `avg` aggregation function (not in its analytic form!):

```
SQL>   SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, ROUND (AVG (e.salary)) avg_sal
  2      FROM departments d
  3            JOIN employees e ON e.department_id = d.department_id
  4  GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department_name;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPAR    AVG_SAL
------------- ----- ----------
            1 IT         76111
            2 DBA       133333

SQL>
```

---

In case you'd want to display department(s) with no employees, you'd use **outer join**:

```
SQL>   SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, ROUND (AVG (e.salary)) avg_sal
  2      FROM departments d
  3           LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.department_id = d.department_id
  4  GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department_name;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPAR    AVG_SAL
------------- ----- ----------
            1 IT         76111
            3 Sales
            2 DBA       133333

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I exclude sales since there are no employees in that department

Comment: Remove LEFT (line #3) so that it "converts" to an inner join. On the other hand, I understood that you *want* to get department(s) with no employees ... Misunderstood what you said, obviously.